# SSLv3 methods disabled error on Google oauth2 requests

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I've tried a variety of Oauth2 packages in an attempt to connect my Node app with Google's oauth2 services -- something I've done successfully in the past.

Right now I'm getting the same error no matter what I try, which is "**SSLv3 methods disabled**".  I'm to understand this was a fairly recent change in Node to disable SSLv3 in order to protect against the POODLE vulnerability in SSL.  My testing shows that if you don't supply your keys and cert with the request object, everything defaults to SSLv3 (which is obviously broken).

The thing is -- none of the popular google oauth2 packages seem to allow the option to pass your own key & cert into the request.  I can monkey-patch my own keys in but, given that this *should* be something affecting a lot of people, I feel like I'm missing something and/or doing something wrong.

Anyone come across this problem and have a more straight-forward solution?

Here's the stack trace;

```
server-0 Error: SSLv3 methods disabled
server-0     at Error (native)
server-0     at new SecureContext (_tls_common.js:23:20)
server-0     at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:42:11)
server-0     at Object.TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.exports.connect (_tls_wrap.js:999:48)
server-0     at Agent.createConnection (https.js:80:22)
server-0     at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:172:16)
server-0     at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:141:23)
server-0     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:137:16)
server-0     at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
server-0     at Object.exports.request (https.js:197:15)
server-0     at Request.start (MY_LOCAL_PATH/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:799:30)
server-0     at Request.write (MY_LOCAL_PATH/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1360:10)
server-0     at end (MY_LOCAL_PATH/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:556:16)
server-0     at Immediate._onImmediate (MY_LOCAL_PATH/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:584:7)
server-0     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

As stated, I have no issues making direct SSL connections manually if I supply my own keys.  The following code works fine;

```
var tls = require ('tls');
var fs = require ('fs');

var options = {
    host: 'google.com',
    port: '443',
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
};

var Stream = tls.connect(options, function () {
    console.log('client connected', Stream.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
    process.stdin.pipe(Stream);
    process.stdin.resume();
});
Stream.on('data', function (stuff) {
    console.log(stuff);
});
Stream.on('end', function () {
    console.log('END');
});
Stream.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
});
```